# 500 internal error on regular linux hosting for php

Tags: php, regex, linux, .htaccess

here is my code in .htaccess

```
<Directory "/">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^custom  contactus.php[NC L]
```

Remote site path or my all website files contains in /www

current url : `example.com/contactus.php`

expected output url: `example.com/custom`

Comment: Please provide error from web server logs. Probably you don't have mod_rewrite module enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom$ /contactus.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Invalid htaccess file

A [Directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) is invalid in a `.htaccess` file:

> **Description**:  Enclose a group of directives that apply only to the
>   named file-system directory, sub-directories, and their contents
>
> **Context**:  server config, virtual host

Note that `.htaccess` is not a valid context. Similarly, [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is also invalid in a `.htaccess` file:

> **Description**:  Types of directives that are allowed in .htaccess files
>
> **Context**:  directory

Were it valid in a `.htaccess` file, it would defeat the purpose of what the directive is for.

### Valid example

The entire contents of the `.htaccess` file to do what's in the question are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^custom  contactus.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I.e. *If* mod rewrite is enabled, apply that rewrite rule. Note that the syntax for [rewrite flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) is a comma separated list.

Comment: I got the solution..
the thing if can we give if conditions in htacces with $_GET method

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but it sounds like a different question.